# How can I iterate through a list?

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I'm super new to Python, 
I want to do a simple loop that iterates through a list which has the name of the months:

I tried For loops like:

```
months=["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]
Max=[]
hours=[]
for m in months:
    time=m.count()/96  # when it goes to "Jan" it has 2976 elements
    for i in range(1,int(time)+1): 
        a=Rdata.m[Rdata.m['Day'] == i].dem.max() # Rdata.Jan is a df which has columsn Day and dem
        b=Rdata.m.loc[Rdata.m['dem']== a,'Time']
    Max.append(a)
    hours.append(b)
```

Just to add more information

I created a list :

```
month= (Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec)
```

in which

```
Jan = Series which contains  2976 elements
```

And I keep getting the error "count() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)"

Comment: please correct you indentation of code

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this here, what do you mean? I copied & paste it from my code

Comment: have you recognized that there are syntactical errors in your code?
BTW count does not work the way you have written. For more info on count refer this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-function-count/

Comment: after for m in months: all your code need indentation , after copy and paste you can format code using code formatter

Comment: You need to have an argument inside of the count() function. If you're trying to count the number of times 'Jan' appears, for instance, you should use count('Jan'). The way you've written this, it appears you want to be counting the instances of 'Jan' found in a list, but instead you are counting the number of times it occurs in a string (that's what 'for m in months' returns).

Comment: you can use `exec` or `eval` I think. `eval("len("+m+")")/96` will resolve to `len(Jan)/96`

Comment: Please don't use `eval`. Use a dictionary instead! Faster, idiomatic, and robust.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq completely agree. If the OP can create a dictionary instead of list - awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enclose the values in double quotes or single quotes they are literal strings not series variables.

Assuming that your code has defined the series from Jan to Dec, you need to create the list months of the series like this:

```
months=[Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec]
```

Answer (score 0):

Count is used for counting the number of elements with the specified value.for example:
fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']

x = fruits.count("cherry")

You should be using len() instead of count there

time=len(m)/96